# to_csv() is changing values with E to Scientific notation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When I save my dataframe to a csv using df.to_csv(). My value that reads "032042E50" is converted to "3.20E+50" in the output csv file.

Is there a way to make sure that these values are saved as they are and that they are not converted to scientific notation?

Comment: Is that how excel is interpreting the data or is that the raw data when you open up the file in a text file?

Comment: It looks like that is partially an excel thing, however when reading and saving it to a new csv again (in my case I am creating several changed csvs) the scientific notation is read into the dataframe.